# How can I define type variant in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am using one VB function into my MVC project Business Object Class.

Sample code in VB:

```
Dim vntPF As Variant
Const INT_PF_USER = 0
Const INT_PF_VENDOR = 1
  strPFUser = ""
  strPFVendor = ""
If (InStr(1, strMerchId, "~") > 0) Then
  vntPF = Split(strMerchId, "~") 
  strPFUser = vntPF(INT_PF_USER)
  strPFVendor = vntPF(INT_PF_VENDOR)
Else
  strPFUser = strMerchId
  strPFVendor = strMerchId
End If
```

This same code I am tring to use in C# class.

```
**Dim vntPayFlow As Variant**

  string strPFUser = string.Empty;
  string strPFVendor = string.Empty;
const int INT_PF_USER = 0;
const int INT_PF_VENDOR = 1;
if (Strings.InStr(1, strMerchId, "~") > 0)
{
    vntPF = Strings.Split(strMerchId, "~");
    strPFUser = vntPF(INT_PF_USER);
    strPFVendor = vntPF(INT_PF_VENDOR);
}
else
{
    strPFUser = strMerchId;
    strPFVendor = strMerchId;
}
```

Here, how to declare that **Dim vntPayFlow As Variant**?

Comment: Why do you need to use `Variant` at all? Use a `String[]` since that's it also in VB.NET. Also try to use VB.NET instead of VB, so for example `String.Split` instead of `Split` or `IndexOf` instead of `InStr`.

Comment: In my understanding `Variant` is not supported by VB.NET at all https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267479%28v=bts.10%29.aspx

Comment: The closest C# equivalent would probably be to declare vntPF as `dynamic`. Not that I'd recommend it in this instance. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that in order to answer your question we have to do a *reverse engeneering*... It looks that you want just to *split* the `strMerchId`, if it *contains 2 items* they should be assigned *separatedly*, if just one then this single item should be assigned to the both `strPFUser` and `strPFVendor`:

```
// Assume that strMerchId is not null
String[] vntPF = strMerchId.Split('~'); // no variant, just an array

if (vntPF.Length == 2) { // Or >= 2
  strPFUser = vntPF[0];
  strPFVendor = vntPF[1];
}
else {
  strPFUser = strMerchId;
  strPFVendor = strMerchId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented you don't need   to use `Variant` at all. Use a `String[]` since that's it also in VB.NET. Also  use VB.NET instead of VB, so for example `String.Split` instead of `Split` or `String.IndexOf` instead of `InStr`. Then it's much easier to convert  since both use .NET.

So like:

```
const int INT_PF_USER = 0;
const int INT_PF_VENDOR = 1;
string strPFUser = strMerchId;   // assignment replaces the else of the following if
string strPFVendor = strMerchId; // assignment replaces the else of the following if
string[] vntPF;
// if you want to know if it is contained you can also use strMerchId.Contains("~")
int indexOfTilde = strMerchId.IndexOf('~');
if(indexOfTilde >= 0) // index starts at 0
{
    vntPF = strMerchId.Split('~');
    strPFUser = vntPF[INT_PF_USER];
    strPFVendor = vntPF[INT_PF_VENDOR];
}
```